# Nmap regarding wrong service name after changing port

Tags: networking, devops, nmap

My issue is that nmap is showing wrong name after changing the port of a service.

I have tried nmap 192.168.17.194, but the service name is showing the wrong name after I changed postgres port to 5436, instead nmap service is showing the jet-driver service name.

Comment: A little bit more information would be great, the commands that you have run, and their output would really help for people to understand the problem and help you resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because nmap is mapping service names with default port numbers. While the port is open, there is no guarantee that it's indeed the expected service that is running on that port. As an example many VPN servers are configured to run on top of port 443 (https).

Use the `-sV` option then. See [Service and Version Detection](https://nmap.org/book/man-version-detection.html)
By default nmap will not make a thorough check against the port (that is more intrusive and noisy).